# Assistance in formulating binary constraint(s)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I would like to seek some advice on modeling the following logical condition:

Given two groups of binary decision variables $A_{i}, i=1...n,$ and $B_{j}, j=1...m$.

$A_{i}=1- B_{j}, \forall i, \forall j$

i.e., if one of $A_{i}=1$, all $B_{j}$ must be zero, and vice-versa.

Besides, the above equality constraint, I would like to include tighter cuts, but have only managed to come up with the following:

$\left\lvert B\right\rvert *A_{i}\le \left\lvert B\right\rvert-\sum_{j=1}^{j=m}B_{j}, \forall i$

$A_{i}\ge 1-\sum_{j=1}^{j=m}B_{j}, \forall i$

Thank you!

Comment: Your first constraint and subsequent description are inconsistent, Did you mean instead $A_i\le 1-B_j$?

Comment: Nope, maybe it would help to retain the first one and ignore the remaining constraints. Thank you.

Comment: I am kinda perplexed, I just both tried the equality and inequality versions. It seems that inequality version outperforms the equality version. May I ask if you could offer some insights? Thank you

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your full model. Probably best to open a separate question for that.

Comment: Sure, thank you!

Comment: Let me redo the ticking again, sorry

Comment: Why do you keep accepting the other answer?

Comment: I just saw your message regarding the other answer. By the other answer, I initially thought you meant the initial answer which you gave. Sorry

Comment: Sorry that my comment was confusing. I meant that you should not accept an answer that violates your desired equality.

Comment: No worries, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Via conjunctive normal form:
$$
A_i \implies \bigwedge_j \lnot B_j \\
\lnot A_i \lor \bigwedge_j \lnot B_j \\
\bigwedge_j (\lnot A_i \lor \lnot B_j) \\
\bigwedge_j (1-A_i +1- B_j\ge 1) \\
\bigwedge_j (A_i +B_j\le 1) \\
$$
The other implication
$$B_j \implies \bigwedge_i \lnot A_i$$
yields the same linear constraints.

From your comment, you also want to enforce
$$\lnot A_i \implies \bigwedge_j B_j,$$
which yields $A_i+B_j\ge 1$.  Together, these two sets of inequality constraints become the equality constraints $A_i+B_j=1$.  There are only two solutions to this linear system, and you can capture that more compactly (with $n+m$ constraints instead of $nm$ constraints) by introducing a single binary variable $z$, with $A_i=z$ for all $i$ and $B_j=1-z$ for all $j$.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an auxiliary variable $z\in\{0,1\}$:

$$
z \geq a_i \ \ \forall a_i \in A
$$

Then you can write:

$$
b_j \leq 1-z \ \ \forall b_j \in B
$$

If $z=0$, then the constraint is redundant. However, if $z=1$, then all elements of $B$ have to be 0.

---

Update: @RobPratt correctly pointed out that the above formulation allows for $a_i = b_j = 0$, which violates the requirement the initial requirements. To fix this, I suggest to add:

$$
z \leq \sum_i a_i \\
\sum_j b_j = 1 -z
$$

Comment: Dear Richard, may I ask if you meant that I should use the two constraints which you suggested to replace the two which I have originally created? Thank you!

Comment: This formulation allows $A_i=0$ and $B_j=0$, which violates $A_i=1-B_j$.

Comment: Unfortunately, your modification is too strong because $\sum_j b_j = 1-z$ allows at most one $b_j$ to be $1$.